# Euclidean classical action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, wick-rotation

This is the Euclidean classical action $S_{cl}[\phi]=\int d^{4}x\ (\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}+U(\phi))$.

It would be nice if somebody could explain the structure of the potential.

I don't understand why $\phi$ is used instead of a position vector $\textbf{r}$. Also, how can $(\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}$ be interpreted as the kinetic energy of the particle? I have integrated the Lagrangian over three spatial coordinates before, but why can the temporal coordinate be integrated over in this expression?

Comment: $U$ is almost completely arbitrary, there's nothing to explain about its "structure". Integrating the Lagrangian density over spacetime is standard in relativistic theories, how else are you going to get manifest Lorentz invariance? $\phi$ is *not* meant to denote a particle, but a *field*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the Euclidean classical action $S_{cl}[\phi]=\int d^{4}x (\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}+U(\phi))$.
>
> It would be nice if somebody could explain the structure of the
>   potential.
>
> I don't understand why $\phi$ is used instead of a position vector
>   $\textbf{r}$. Also, how can $(\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}$ be
>   interpreted as the kinetic energy of the particle? I have integrated
>   the Lagrangian over three spatial coordinates before, but why can the
>   temporal coordinate be integrated over in this expression?

The integration over time, is from the definition of the *action*:
$$
S=\int dt L\;,
$$
where $L$ is the *Lagrangian*.

The integration over space is there because (by your choice) you are considering a Lagrangian that is equal to the integral over all space of a *Lagrangian density*
$$
L=\int d^3x \mathcal{L}\;,
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{L}\equiv (\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}+U(\phi))\;.
$$

The function $U$ is unspecified in your question. It could have pretty much any functional form you want. For example, it could be simple a quadradic function:
$$
U(\phi)=\alpha\phi^2+\beta\phi+\gamma\;,
$$

For example, with $\alpha=k/2$, $\beta=0$, and $\gamma=0$ you would have
$$
S=\int dt d^3x (\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}+\frac{k}{2}\phi^2)\;.
$$

The field $\phi(\vec r)$ is treated as the variable when calculating the equations of motion because that is what you are ostensibly interested in (this is a field theory)... there are no "particles" in this theory because (as you stated) this is a classical action and the fields are classical fields (i.e., just regular functions, not operator-valued functions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if $S_{cl}[\phi]$ is standard notation to denote the classical Euclidean action. What exactly is the word 'Euclidean' supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: Look it up in Wikipedia,  it's a geometry where eculid's five  axioms apply.

Comment: I know what Euclidean means. I just don't understand why this expression applies to Euclidean space-time and what modifications might lead to Minkowski space-time. Can you suggest online resources that discuss this classical Euclidean action?

Comment: Sorry, you did ask what the word meant and I told you. You are contradicting yourself.  Anyway move on from that, I would still look up wiki. Euclidian spacetime is a wrong phrase to use, euclidean space is better because  time is treated separately from space. Minkowski spacetime is okay to use,  it treats space and time together, in a 4 dimensional universe. The action you used in your question goes to a 4 d version on mk spacetime.

Comment: Look up classical action on wiki, it's same idea as euclidean action. Plenty of lecture notes on it too online, take you no time to find them.

Comment: @failexam In real space-time the metric is given by g=diag(-1,+1,+1,+1) [or by g=(+1,-1,-1,-1) if you prefer *awful* conventions]. In euclidean space-time the metric is given by g=diag(+1,+1,+1,+1). Most books on QFT will discuss "wick rotation" to euclidean space time. For example, the book by Peskin and Schroder. There is not enough space in the comments for a full discussion of this point. If you have another question, just point another question.